# iptables not logging to /var/log/messages on centos 7

Tags: centos, iptables

I am trying to set up IP Tables on CentOS 7 which I've done in the past but for some reason I can't get it to log the dropped packets like I'd expect. 
In the ip tables config I have the following

```
*filter
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited



# Log and drop packets that don't match the above rules
-N LOGGING
-A INPUT -j LOGGING
-A OUTPUT -j LOGGING
-A LOGGING -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables-Dropped: " --log-level 6
-A LOGGING -j REJECT
-A INPUT -j REJECT
-A OUTPUT -j REJECT
COMMIT
```

As you can see I only have port 22 (SSH) open so I would expect if I try and do an HTTP request, because this isn't allowed in the firewall, it would block the request (which it does) but I should also see in /var/log/messages the log line `IPTables-Dropped` which I don't.

I've also tried updating /etc/rsyslog.conf and added `kern.warn /var/log/messages` but doesn't make any difference (I did restart rsyslog service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order of rules does matter.

This rule:

```
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

precedes this rule:

```
-A INPUT -j LOGGING
```

preventing it to ever be executed: no logging.

Same for other chains.

Just use `iptables-save` to output a "refreshed" version of your rules, and edit their order accordingly.

Also read [this link](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/patch/20200603133604.7169-1-jengelh@inai.de/) about the (very rarely happening) problem of using `REJECT` without first `DROP`-ing INVALID states.

Comment: Thanks that was it, I knew the order mattered, but I thought the --reject-with icmp... was related to blocking ICMP traffic such as `ping` and `tracert`

Comment: no, you'd place the icmp filter before (`-p icmp` would be enough). Note that blindly filtering *all* ICMP can cause other issues, especially about PMTUD (and thus VPN tunnels).

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, don't think I'll be needing PMTUD from a quick look and definetely won't be using VPN tunnels.